# Grunt.js - Tasks Mutual Invocation

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to find out if there's a (clean) way of manually invoke one task from within another one.

My case is I need to concatenate several scripts into bundles, so something like "concat", but I need to make up the configuration from the results of another task.

Initially, I was about to implement the concatenation myself but I found it a bit sad to re-implement something that already exists like grunt-contrib-concat - which I could simply use by providing it the configuration data resulting from tasks previously run.

So, in that case, is there a way to invoke "concat" manually from within some other task and provide it an appropriate configuration block/object?

Also, I don't want to declare anything for "concat" itself in my configuration.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: If you need clarification for anything, let me know or stop by #grunt on freenode.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for the `concat` task you can use the [grunt-lib-legacyhelpers](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-legacyhelpers) package.

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
  var helpers = require( 'grunt-lib-legacyhelpers' ).init( grunt );

  // …

  var src = helpers.concat( files );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely have a look into it when I come back to my work on grunt.

Comment: There's probably something to try with `grunt.task.run`: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run